# How to isolate a column of a reactive dataframe in R shiny in order to execute a math operation on it?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In the below demo code I run a simple example of a reactive dataframe called `choice1`. I am trying to make a copy of `choice1`, called `choice2`, and simply multiply the right-most column (named "Values" in the `data` DF) of `choice2` by a factor of 2. `Choice1` renders correctly.

The below demo code almost works, except that when run the 2nd column of `choice2` (named "Period" in `choice1` and the `data` DF and should have the same name in `choice2`) doesn't render despite my including it in the `cbind()` below, and I also lose the column names leaving me with only V1 and V2 in the rendering of `choice2`. How do I resolve this? Also, is there a cleaner way to do this in base R? For now I'm avoiding other packages since I'm at this early stage just trying to learn R, Shiny, and reactivity.

Demo code:

```
library(shiny)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4)
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h5(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(inputId = "showData",
               label = h5(strong("Show from original dataframe:")),
               choiceNames = c('All','First 4 rows'),
               choiceValues = c('All','Rows'),
               selected = 'All',
               inline = TRUE
              ),
  h5(strong("Reactive results:")), 
  tableOutput("choices1"),
  h5(strong("Mirrow results x 2:")), 
  tableOutput("choices2")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
# reactiveValues is for multiple reactive values, whereas reactiveVal is for a single reactive value
  rv <- reactiveValues(choices1=c()) 
  observeEvent(input$showData, {
      if(input$showData == 'Rows'){rv$choices1 <- data[1:4,]} 
      else {rv$choices1 <- data}
      }
    )
  
  output[["choices1"]] <- renderTable({rv$choices1})

  output[["choices2"]] <- renderTable({cbind(rv$choices1[,1],rv$choices[,2],rv$choices1[,3] * 2)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
output[["choices2"]] <- renderTable({
  dat <- rv$choices
  dat[, 3] <- 2 * dat[, 3]
  dat
})
```

Comment: Works beautifully. One small fix: the dat <- rv$choices should be dat <- rv$choices1